# how to profile the time consumption and cpu usage in the c++ version tensorflow when model predict?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, time, profile, consumption

I trained the model in python-tensorflow, and profile the time consumption, I optimized the high consumption function but in the c++ version tf, it did not work, anyone who knows?

Comment: We'll show you ours if you show us yours.

Comment: this is information: Net (0B/145.58MB, 0us/1.86sec, 0us/0us, 0us/1.86sec), after optimized, change to NetNet (0B/79.22MB, 0us/397.76ms, 0us/0us, 0us/397.76ms).

Comment: I meant your attempts.

Comment: In python version, using the https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/profiler/README.md, provided by google, I modified some ops according the report results, it is easy to get. But in c++ tf, I did not find any api or function to profile the time consumption.